# Can't resolve all parameters for MapsPage:(?,NavController,LaunchNavigator,.......) in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

so I am using Angular2 with Ionic2 for my mobile application. My application was compiling and running perfectly until I added a new module to the application to have navigation in google maps. I am using phonegap-launch-navigator to do so. The class where I am importing the modules is my Maps class and the structure of the class looks like this;

```
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions} from 'ionic-native';
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController, Platform, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng, GoogleMapsMarkerOptions, CameraPosition } from 'ionic-native';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Injectable,forwardRef,Inject } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  selector: 'maps-page',
  templateUrl: 'maps.html',
})

export class MapsPage {

  private map: GoogleMap;
  destination:string;
  start:string;

  constructor(public LaunchNavigatorOptions: LaunchNavigatorOptions,
    private _navController: NavController,
    private LaunchNavigator:LaunchNavigator,
    private platform: Platform,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private _zone: NgZone) {
    this.start = "";
    this.destination = "Westminster, London, UK";
    this.platform.ready().then(() => this.onPlatformReady());
  }
```

and my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "myApp: An Ionic project"
}
```

After importing these two modules and putting them in the constructor, I am not able to even start my application and it gives a runtime error saying "Can't resolve all parameters for MapsPage(?,NavController,LaunchNavigator,Platform,NavController,NavParams,NgZone). I think the problem is with LaunchNavigatorOptions because when i comment that one specifically out, the application is able to run again without any problems. Is there anything that I can do to make it work? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Sampath, I edited my post. You can see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using *ionic-native v2.2.11*.

In this version the plugins are global and static and are not supposed to be injected in the constructor.
Just remove

```
public LaunchNavigatorOptions: LaunchNavigatorOptions
```

and

```
private LaunchNavigator:LaunchNavigator,
```

from your constructor.

check the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/) for upgrading to ionic-native 3.x

Comment: How can I use LaunchNavigatorOptions and Launch Navigator in my class then?